# Align an image to the left in a UINavigationBar

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I want to show a background image on my app's navigation bar.
Showing the image works:

```
UIImage image =  new UIImage( @"Images/navbarlogo2.png");
UIImageView imageview = new UIImageView(image);
NavigationItem.TitleView = imageview;
```

But the image is centered, while I need it to be right-aligned.

I have not been able to find a property to do this, and searching yielded no answers.

Comment: create the image with right aligned logo hope it will work.

Comment: @sanjitshaw The screen sizes between iPhone 3Gs and later differ.

Comment: NavigationBar height differs but width is same for all iPhone or iPod touch I think

Comment: @sanjitshaw No, they do differ: 3GS is 480px width, later phones are 640 px width

Comment: Yes number of pixel differs 320px and 640px but not the screen width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following method to set your navbar's background image. Note that this will set it as the default for all the nav bars and is available since iOS5.

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(image, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

Comment: Where do I implement this?

Comment: You can set this in AppDelegate DidFinishedLaunching before setting yout RootViewController.

Comment: Thank you, this was a good answer. Do you know how to stop a small image from tiling?

Comment: Hmm not sure since the bg image for navbar is usually a pattern image. If you don't want it to tile, you would need to get back at your first try, set the imageView contentMode to Right and set imageView.Frame = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds; it should work